# Does GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB only work for Front/Back Buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to use GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB to write sRGB space values to a framebuffer, but I find the call of glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB) only work for Front/Back buffer, and not work for other framebuffers created from textures.

my pipeline is like this:

1. first is scene stage that renders the scene to a GL_RGB10_A2 buffer;
2. then a post-process stage that renders to a GL_RGB8(0x8051) buffer,
3. post-process chain that eventually renders to Front/Back buffer.

I try to do glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB) for every stage. Since all render buffer is not sRGB format so the next stage will not automatic do any sRGB to linear conversion, and I don't do any conversion in the shader either, I should be expecting the final result becomes extremely bright because of multiple linear-to-sRGB conversions. but it only works for the last stage which is rendering to Front/Back buffer, so the final result doesn't get extremely bright.

I tried few more format for render buffer(GL_RGB8, GL_RGBA8, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8), still not work.

Did I miss something from the spec? using GTX750 with the latest driver on win7.

Comment: How do you tell if it isn't working?

Comment: @NicolBolas because I have a post-process chain, which I enable GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB for every stage, and input linear value into it. With multiple stage, it should do multiple linear-to-sRGB conversion but it didn’t.

Comment: Right, but how you do know that it isn't working? What are you doing that verifies that you aren't getting linear-to-sRGB conversion?

Comment: @NicolBolas I was doing the linear-to-sRGB conversion in shader before, now I remove the conversion from the shader, and the result image is darker than I expect. Also I tried enable and disable GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB for the first stage of my post-process pipeline (I call the API before and after the actual DrawElements call), it didn’t give different result as it should.

Answer (score 1):

First what the [OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) spec says (emphasis mine):

> Section 17.3.6.1 Blend Equation
>
> If FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is enabled and the value of FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING for the framebuffer attachment corresponding to the destination buffer is SRGB (see section 9.2.3), **the R, G, and B destination color values (after conversion from fixed-point to floating-point) are considered to be encoded for the sRGB color space** and hence must be linearized prior to their use in blending. Each R, G, and B component is converted in the same fashion described for sRGB texture components in section 8.24.
>
> **If FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is disabled or the value of FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING is not SRGB, no linearization is performed.**
>
> The resulting linearized R, G, and B and unmodified A values are recombined as the destination color used in blending computations. Table 17.1 provides the corresponding per-component
>
> 17.3.7 sRGB Conversion **(occurs after blending)**
>
> If FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is enabled and the value of FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING for the framebuffer attachment corresponding to the destination buffer is SRGB (see section 9.2.3), the R, G, and B values after blending are converted into the non-linear sRGB color space by computing [`cs = sRGB(cl)`] where cl is the R, G, or B element and cs is the result (effectively converted into an sRGB color space).
>
> **If FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is disabled or the value of FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING is not SRGB, then `cs = cl`**. The resulting cs values for R, G, and B, and the unmodified A form a new RGBA color value.

2 things stands out for me in relation to your case:

1. Check the value of `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING`
2. Part of the process only happens if blending is enabled.

The main purpose of OpenGL's sRGB support is to be able to output sRGB colors and have them blend properly in a linear space.

Comment: Why the -1 vote? I mostly quoted relevant parts of the spec.

Comment: Added source (4.6 core) and adjusted paragraph numbers. The same text is present in previous versions of the spec as well in other paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried GL_RGB8, GL_RGBA8, and GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, but not GL_SRGB8, and the last one worked.